# Верно ли использовать AUTO_INCREMENT как идентификатор в странице пользователя

Tags: mysql

Как ведет себе AUTO_INCREMENT, допустим, при переносе БД?

Если в базе обнаружатся пропуски id, то не пересчитаются ли значения при переносе? Ведь в таком случае все адреса пользовательских страниц изменятся.

Верно ли привязывать адрес к такому айди? 
Или нужно создавать отдельное поле для этого?

Comment: `mysqldump` копирует `as is`. то есть как есть. ....будут строки в дампе типа `Insert into table (id, col1, col2, col3) values (1, 'val1', 'val2', 'val3'), (55, 'val1', 'val2', 'val3'), (99, 'val1', 'val2', 'val3')`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а вообще, верен ли такой подход в формировании адресов страниц?

Comment: Какой такой? ну весь мир использует в качестве идентификатора страницы/пользователя/новости/статьи/пр.  `id`.

Comment: Заметь, даже у данной страницы стоит `id` 680533. Хотя вопросы частенько удаляются и данные могут переносится между центрами. ничё, живет еще)

Comment: *Как ведет себе AUTO_INCREMENT, допустим, при переносе БД?* Он ведёт себя в точности так, как задано кодом/настройками средств переноса. Половина таких средств оставит ID без изменения, другая половина - безусловно изменит все значения (если какие-то не изменятся - это просто случайное совпадение старого и нового значений).